# Сортировка HashMap

Tags: java

Помогите пожалуйста отсортировать HashMap по Integer.

```
  int rate = 8;//8,16,24
            HashMap<String, Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
            int counter = 0;
            StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
                counter++;
                buffer.append(string.charAt(i));
                if (counter == rate) {
                    counter = 0;
                    Integer frequency = hashMap.get(buffer.toString());
                    hashMap.put(buffer.toString(), frequency == null ? 1 : frequency + 1);
                    buffer = new StringBuilder();
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Частотный анализ "+ rate + " грамм :: ");
            String[] arrayKey = hashMap.keySet().toArray(new String[0]);

            for (int k = 0; k < arrayKey.length; k++)
            {
                System.out.println( arrayKey[k] + " - " + hashMap.get(arrayKey[k]));
            }
```

Comment: HashMap изначально не может быть отсортирован, вы сначала разберитесь с тем как работают мапы а потом пытайтесь их сортировать или что то делать, в Вашем случае можо использовать TreeMap

Comment: @JVic предлагаете использовать `TreeMap` для сортировки по **значениям**?

Comment: Зачем вам вообще сортировать hashmap?

Comment: @Regent упс, не доконца вник в условие, но увидев, что нужно сортировать мапу сразу подумал о TreeMap. Тогда вопрос стоит о целесообразности сортировки мапы по значениям и возможно стоит перстроить структуру данных

Comment: @BogdanBida скорее всего, автору нужно вывести результаты в нужном порядке. В этом случае "отсортировать HashMap" - просто неудачная формулировка.

Answer (score 7):

Вывод содержимого по возрастанию значения:

```
map.entrySet().stream()
        .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Если нужен обратный порядок:

```
map.entrySet().stream()
        .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder()))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Если нужно все это сложить в `Map`, сохранив порядок:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> orderedMap = map.entrySet().stream()
        .sorted(Entry.comparingByValue())
        .collect(LinkedHashMap::new,
                (m, c) -> m.put(c.getKey(), c.getValue()),
                LinkedHashMap::putAll);
```

Answer (score 3):

Отсортировать непосредственно `HashMap` нельзя. Если нужно просто вывести на экран пары "ключ - значение" в порядке возрастания значений, то сделать это можно так:

```
hashMap.entrySet().stream()
                  .sorted(Entry.comparingByValue())
                  .forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.getKey() + " - " + e.getValue()));
```

Для вывода по убыванию `int`-значений:

```
.sorted(Entry.comparingByValue((a, b) -> b - a))
```